# RGB and Depth video from raspberry pi 2

Tags: kinect, rgb, raspberry-pi2, depth

I am trying to visualize both RGB and depth images from a Kinect (older version) using my Raspberry Pi 2. I've managed to stream the depth image following this great [post](https://github.com/xxorde/librekinect/), but I would also like to stream the RGB content so I can analyze both simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to capture RGB and depth data **simultaneously** with *librekinect*. If you are willing to try a different library, you can use [*libfreenect*](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect), which allows you to do just what you need.